# Проблема с Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, бот

После окончания работы кода, он ломается. После этого он вообще не работает. Я новичок и только учусь (Использую pyTelegramBotAPI).

```
import telebot
import os, signal, pickle, sys

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def privetctive(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Здравствуйте, как я могу к вам обращаться?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, repeat_all_messages)
    doc = open('file.txt', 'w')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    user_markup.row('Test1', 'Test2')
    uslugi = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Какие услуги вас интересуют?", reply_markup=user_markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(uslugi, telephon)
    doc = open('file.txt', 'a')
    doc.write("Имя заказчика - {name}\n".format(name=message.text))


def telephon(message):
    nomer = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Оставьте ваш контактный номер чтобы наш менеджер смог связаться с вами.')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(nomer, poka)
    doc = open('file.txt', 'a')
    doc.write("Услуга - {services}\n".format(services=message.text))


def poka(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Спасибо за обращение. Мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время.')
    doc = open('file.txt', 'a')
    doc.write("Телефон - {telephone}\n".format(telephone=message.text))
    doc.close()
    file_to_send = open('file.txt', 'r')
    bot.send_document(1, file_to_send)
    file_to_send.close()
    os.remove('file.txt')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling()
```

Сообщение в консоли:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Users\Zako\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)  

  File "c:/Users/Zako/Desktop/PYprac/Practice.py", line 37, in poka
    bot.send_document(1, file_to_send)

  File "C:\Users\Zako\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 687, in send_document
    parse_mode, disable_notification, timeout, caption=caption))   

  File "C:\Users\Zako\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 489, in send_data
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, files=files, method='post')   

  File "C:\Users\Zako\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 56, in _make_request
    return _check_result(method_name, result)['result']   

  File "C:\Users\Zako\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 75, in _check_result
    raise ApiException(msg, method_name, result)
telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: chat not found"}']  

2020-01-05 14:16:47,437 (__init__.py:417 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: chat not found"}']"
```

**Нужно сделать так чтобы он продолжал работать**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ:

```
file_to_send = open('client.txt', 'rb')
bot.send_document(chat_id=chat_id, data=file_to_send)
file_to_send.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска бота используйте `bot.infinity_polling(none_stop=True)` вместо `bot.polling()`. *По факту `infinity_polling` оборачивает `polling` в try\exept*

Он ошибка у Вас chat not found вызвана не этим...возможно вы не правильно получаете `message.chat.id`

Comment: Я понял как исправить проблему с крахом кода, но все равно спасибо.